# Is v-spec Specific for agent? If so, How to Solve This Problem?

Tags: verbs, movement, theta-role

In my syntax classes, I learnt that v-spec is specific for `agent` role. The thing is, I came across a structure in the resource below:

> Radford, A. (2004). Minimalist Syntax: Exploring the Structure of English

He was analyzing the structure of sentence below:

```
Where is it thought that he will go?
```

So at first, he gave a structure as below:

[image]

And then he said:

> Since vP is intransitive (by virtue of the fact that the light verb has no external argument), vP is not a phase, and Transfer cannot apply at this point.

What does that mean? I learned that an `agent` *must always be* at v-spec and `he` is really and `agent` there. I -at first- thought that `go` does not have any accusative argument, so `he` is at V-spec, but that did not make any sense at all. So, from this point, it went through this way below:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is there really any reference that an `agent` occurs in another place rather than v-spec?
2. If it is possible to see `agent`s in another place, does that apply to all verbs not having an accusative argument but only a `PP`?
3. If `agent` is specific to `v-spec`, then how do we describe the given example above?

## Limitations

- Phase Theory must be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew Radford (Radford 2004) discusses it on p. 351.

Go is an unaccusative verb, which means, under **Radford**'s analysis, that **the subject originates in spec-VP**, unlike in the case of transitive (unergative) verbs, where the subject originates in spec-vP.

This is what Radford proposed. However, it doesn't mean that everyone has the same interpretation of the syntactic behavior of intransitive (unaccusative) verbs.

David **Adger** (Adger 2003, Core Syntax) argues that **the argument** of an unaccusative verb (THEME) is always **base-generated in comp,VP** - so, at least his analysis is better in this regard because it doesn't violate UTAH. The argument then moves to spec,TP (to satisfy EPP on T).

Comment: There are other analyses, as well, which satisfy Occam's Razor more thoroughly.

Comment: @jlawler of course, but since the question is specifically tied to Radford, I wrote what Radford proposed and not someone else.